# What does a double underscore mean in a Python import statement?

Tags: python

The [documentation for Amazon Neptune](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-python.html) contains the following code sample.

```
from __future__  import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()

remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection('wss://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/gremlin','g')
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)

print(g.V().limit(2).toList())
remoteConn.close()
```

**Question**: What does the double underscore mean in line number 4?

Since this is being used in an import statement, it must somehow be different than ["name mangling" in Python class definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name). I'm just not clear on what it's intended to do.

Comment: It's just an identifier. Apparently `gremlin_python.proces.graph_traversal` defines something named `__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing special. You can find [the code online](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/python/gremlin_python/process/graph_traversal.py#L608) and see there is a class with that name in the package that is being imported.